# How to create a JSTree view with context menu with create, rename, delete, drag'n'drop with PHP/Laravel? This is the Full solution

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, jstree, laravel-8

My project needed a file treeview to upload documents and I was using a theme forest template with jstree included in a page.

So I've decided to use it but it was necessary to connect it to the database. It was needed a database, an api and all the code for it.

I've spent some hours trying to find out how to create a JSTree Structure with Laravel, with drag and drop, moving, creating, renaming and sorting features.

Answer (score 5):

After digging into the jstree documentation and Stack Overflow, here is my working solution compilation of everything, step by step.

I'm using JSTree version 3.3.11 and Laravel 8.

Steps:

A) Create Database.
The table is "Directories".

```
    class CreateDirectoriesTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('directories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->text('observations')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->foreign('parent_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('directories')
                    ->cascadeOnDelete();
    
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('directories');
        }
    }
```

B) Directory.model
Use it to define which fields are updatable, and to define the recursive relationship.
<?php

```
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Directory extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        
        protected $fillable = [
            'parent_id',
            'name',
            'observations',
        ];
    
        public function children()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Directory::class, 'parent_id');
        }
    
    }
```

C) Seeder (optional)
I've used a Seeder to include some items to test

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Faker\Factory;
use App\Models\Directory;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DirectorySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $items = array(
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => null,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => null,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => null,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => null,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 1,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 2,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 3,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 5,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 5,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 7,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 7,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 8,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            [
                'name' => $faker->lexify('???????????????'),
                'parent_id' => 8,
                'observations' => $faker->optional()->paragraph(3),
            ],
            

        );
        
        foreach($items as $item) { 
            Directory::factory()->create($item);         
        }    
    }
}
```

D) Routes on web.php
I've defined the 4 functions to deal with DragNDrop, Rename, Delete and Create.

```
Route::name('api.')->prefix('api/')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/treeview/dnd', 'ApiController@treeviewDnd')->name('treeviewdnd');
    Route::post('/treeview/rename', 'ApiController@treeviewRename')->name('treeviewrename');
    Route::post('/treeview/delete', 'ApiController@treeviewDelete')->name('treeviewdelete');
    Route::post('/treeview/create', 'ApiController@treeviewCreate')->name('treeviewcreate');
});
```

E) The API Controller

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    // Move Node on Directory Tree
    public function treeviewDnd()
    {
        $directory = Directory::find(request()->source);
        if ($directory) {
            if (request()->destination) {
                if (request()->destination == '#') {
                    $directory->parent_id = null;
                } else {
                    $directory->parent_id = request()->destination;
                }
            } 
            $directory->update();
        }
    }

    // Rename Node on Directory Tree
    public function treeviewRename()
    {
        $directory = Directory::find(request()->dbid);
    
        if ($directory) {
            $name = request()->name;
            if ($name) {            
                $directory->name = $name;
                $directory->update();
            }    
        }
    }

    // Delete Node on Directory Tree
    public function treeviewDelete()
    {        
        $directory = Directory::find(request()->id);
        
        if ($directory) {
            $directory->delete();
        }

    }

    // Create Node on Directory Tree
    public function treeviewCreate()
    {
        $directory = [
            "name" => request()->name,
            "parent_id" => request()->parentid,
        ];
        $result = Directory::create($directory);
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

F) Include tree on blade.php

```
<div id="stackoverflowtree" class="tree-demo"></div>
```

G) I've created a section "SCRIPTS" on my base blade, so I can include scripts at the end of the page using the section tag.

```
@section('scripts')

    <script>
        "use strict";
        var tree = {!! $treeJS !!};
        var treeId = '#stackoverflowtree';

        var nodeSelected = undefined;
        
        var KTTreeview = function () {
            var _demostackoverflow = function() {
                $(treeId).jstree({
                    "core" : {
                        "themes" : {
                            "responsive": false
                        },
                        // so that create works
                        "check_callback" : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
                            if (operation === 'delete_node') {
                                if (confirm('@lang("global.confirmation_title")') == true) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
                        'data': tree,
                    },
                    "types" : {
                        "default" : {
                            "icon" : "fa fa-folder text-primary"
                        },
                        "file" : {
                            "icon" : "fa fa-file text-primary"
                        }
                    },
                    "state" : { "key" : "demo2" },
                    "plugins" : [ "dnd", "state", "types", "sort", "contextmenu" ],
                    "sort" : function(a, b) {                
                        if (a && b && this) {
                            var a1 = this.get_node(a);
                            var b1 = this.get_node(b);
                            
                            if (a1.icon == b1.icon){
                                return a1.text.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b1.text.toLowerCase());
                            } else {
                                return a1.icon.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b1.icon.toLowerCase());
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "contextmenu": {
                        "items": function ($node) {
                            var tree = $(treeId).jstree(true);
                            return {
                                "Rename": {
                                    "label": "@lang('global.directory_rename')",
                                    "action": function (obj) { 
                                        tree.edit($node);
                                    }
                                },
                                "Create": {
                                    "label": "@lang('global.directory_create')",
                                    "action": function (obj) { 
                                        $node = tree.create_node($node);
                                        tree.edit($node); 
                                    }
                                },
                                "Delete": {
                                    "label" : "@lang('global.directory_delete')",
                                    "action" : function(obj) { 
                                        tree.delete_node($node);
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
                })
                .bind("move_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
                    var treeInst = $(treeId).jstree(true);
                
                    var parentNodeResult = null;
                    if (data.parent != '#') {
                        var aux = treeInst.get_node(data.parent);
                        parentNodeResult = aux.original.dbid;
                    } else {
                        parentNodeResult = '#';
                    }
                
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('api.treeviewdnd') }}",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {
                            "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                            "source": data.node.original.dbid, 
                            "destination": parentNodeResult,
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                })
                .bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data){
                    console.log("select");
                    nodeSelected = data.node;

                    $("#tree-subtitle").html(data.node.text)
                    
                })
                .bind("rename_node.jstree", function (e, data) {    
                    if (data.node.text && data.text != data.old) {    
                        
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{ route('api.treeviewrename') }}",
                            type:'POST',
                            data: {
                                "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                                "dbid": data.node.original.dbid, 
                                "name": data.text,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                toastr.success('@lang("global.success_message")', '@lang("global.success_title")');
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                toastr.error('@lang("global.error_required")', '@lang("global.error_title")');
                            }
                        });
                    }    
                })
                .bind("create_node.jstree", function (e, data) {    

                    var treeInst = $(treeId).jstree(true)
                    var parentNode = treeInst.get_node(data.parent)
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('api.treeviewcreate') }}",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {
                            "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                            "entityid": {{ $entity->id }}, 
                            "parentid": parentNode.original.dbid, 
                            "name": data.node.text,
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            data.node.original = { "dbid" : response.id };
                        },
                        error: function(response) {
                            toastr.error('@lang("global.error_message")', '@lang("global.error_title")');
                        }
                    });
                    
                })
                .bind("delete_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('api.treeviewdelete') }}",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {
                            "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                            "id": data.node.original.dbid, 
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            toastr.success('@lang("global.success_message")', '@lang("global.success_title")');
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            toastr.error('@lang("global.error_message")', '@lang("global.error_title")');
                        }
                    });
                
                });
            }

            
            return {
                //main function to initiate the module
                init: function () {
                    _demostackoverflow();
                }
            };
        }();        
        
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            KTTreeview.init();
        });
     
    </script>
@endsection
```

H) I almost forgot. The creation of the tree structure on the server side, the page Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Directory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EntityController extends Controller
{

    private function getTreeJS($entity, $path_id, &$treejs)
    {
        
        $directories = Directory::where('entity_id', $entity->id)->where('parent_id', $path_id)->get();
        
        $treejs .= '[';
        foreach($directories as $directory) {
            $treejs .= '{';
                $treejs .= '    "dbid" : "' . $directory->id . '", ';
                $treejs .= '    "text" : "' . $directory->name . '", ';
                
                $treejs .= '"children" : ';
                
            $treejs .= $this->getTreeJS($entity, $directory->id, $treejs);
            
        
            $treejs .= '}, ';
        }
        $treejs .= ']';
    }

    public function details(Entity $entity, Property $property = null)
    {
        // Create Tree JS
        $treejs = '';
        $this->getTreeJS($entity, null, $treejs);
        
        return view('admin.entities.details', [
            'treeJS' => $treejs,    
        ]);
    }
}
```

I) The messages I've used to show some output to the user are in language files /resources/lang/en/ in Laravel:

```
<?php

return [
    // Success
    'success_title' => 'Success!',
    'success_message' => 'Operation successfully.',
    
    // Errors
    'error_title' => 'Ups! There was an error.',
    'error_required' => 'You must fill the information.',
    'error_message' => 'It was not possible to finish the operation.',
    
    'confirmation_title' => 'Do you confirm?',
    'confirmation_success' => 'Operation successfully.',

    'directory_rename' => 'Rename',
    'directory_create' => 'Create folder',
    'directory_delete' => 'Delete folder'
];
```

Conclusion:
I've used an extra variable called dbid for each tree folder corresponding to the ID on my database table.

Using that DB Id, I can use it on each operation by finding the exact node using the jstree 'get_node'.

I've just started learning Laravel and this is not the perfect solution but it was my approach to handle my requirements. Feel free to use it and change it your own way.

This is my image:

[image: Jstree context menu]